# Guzzle query string prameters

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm having problems writing my request. I need to provide query string parameters to `GET` method using `request()`. Since I'm writing tests I can't edit the method.

Right now I have it written like this:

```
$result = $client->request(
                'GET',
                'cart/current/get-items',
                [
                    'headers' => [
                        'X-AUTH-API-TOKEN' => 'Bearer ' . $tokens->token
                    ],
                    'query'=>[
                        'paginator_data'=>[
                            'page'=>1,
                            'page_size' => 10
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
```

Method that gets `paginator_data`:

```
 $paginatorData = json_decode($request->query->get('paginator_data'), true);
```

And thats how `query` looks if I check the `request` testing it from the front-end:

Source:

```
paginator_data=%7B%22page%22:1,%22page_size%22:10%7D
```

Parsed:

```
paginator_data: {"page":1,"page_size":10}
```

how do I format the `query` to make it look like the `Source` one? Because if I copy paste it inside my query it works.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: @MC57 how do I format the `query` to make it look like the `Source` one?

Comment: what you get from your encoded url (`paginator_data=%7B%22page%22:1,%22page_size%22:10%7D`) is `paginator_data={"page":1,"page_size":10}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you maybe need to `json_encode` your data:

```php
$result = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'cart/current/get-items',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'X-AUTH-API-TOKEN' => 'Bearer ' . $tokens->token
        ],
        'query'=>[
            'paginator_data'=> json_encode([
                'page'=>1,
                'page_size' => 10
            ])
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: @AlphaKennyBuddy What error do you receive?

Comment: Sorry must have been my mistake, tried it again and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urlencode(string $string): string`. See [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
echo urlencode('paginator_data: {"page":1,"page_size":10}');
// will give output paginator_data%3A+%7B%22page%22%3A1%2C%22page_size%22%3A10%7D
```

Comment: I need to get `paginator_data=%7B%22page%22:1,%22page_size%22:10%7D` and it gives me `paginator_data%3A+%7B%22page%22%3A1%2C%22page_size%22%3A10%7D"` and the method fails.